# Suppress individual warning with closure compiler linter

Tags: javascript, lint, google-closure-compiler

I'm using closure compiler to lint and compile my javascript like this:

```
java -jar closure-compiler-v20190528.jar --jscomp_warning=lintChecks --js in.js --js_output_file out.js
```

I'd like to suppress the warning

```
JSC_MISSING_JSDOC
```

on the command line (don't want to modify my javascript).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, seems like a good feature request though.